# Talker crashes terminates instantly?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why does this publisher terminate.. I don't have a clue ..
Code can be seen here.

[pastebin.com/NGy9qwTm](http://pastebin.com/NGy9qwTm)

It should just enter the values within the vector to the variable, and wait 1 second and then do it again..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208291/talker-crashes-terminates-instantly?/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-05-01

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on 2015-05-01**:
Is there any terminal output when it crashes? Do you get an error message, or does the program simply end?

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-05-01**:
it just simply end..  The terminal says that it finished cleanly.. ..

**Comment by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on 2015-05-01**:
is "re" being printed? How many times?
What have you tried?

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-05-01**:
So.. the talker and listener gets launched using xterm.   and  talker is opens instantly, and then closes..  So i am not able to see what it actually says..

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-05-01**:
even if i set the sleep duration to be 100000 it opens instantly and closes.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-05-01**:
Ok... i narrowed it down into being something with the way i am converting.. because as soon it gets set it terminates.

**Comment by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on 2015-05-01**:
Try to launch the talker using rosrun, so you can see its output in the terminal. Start adding printout statements to ensure that your program gets to each line, beginning at the very start of the program.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-05-01**:
It seems to terminate when the variable is set from the vector...

**Comment by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on 2015-05-01**:
You call multiple vectors in your code. What line causes the crash?

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-05-02**:
it crashes at line 93.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a question that's more appropriate for StackOverflow - it's a general programming issue.

With that being said: if you're getting an error on line 93, it's because `values` doesn't contain an element at position `i`. Attempting to access this location in the vector causes your program to crash because the location doesn't exist in the vector.

Your `i` variable will loop from 0 to 100, which means it will try 101 vector elements. Ensure that you have at least this many elements in your vector by checking `values.size()` or printing it to the terminal.

Finally, just as a note, your code contains no way to break out of your loop. It will continue to check the `i=100` element over and over until ROS is killed.

---

Originally posted by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) with karma: 194 on 2015-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-05-02**:
Problem wasn't in this file, but due some other node.  I will delete since answering it here doesn't make any sense..